# Eloquent resulting single search result as array not collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have some instances where a eloquent is resulting an single array not a collection. Although dd shows it as a collection with a single entry.

For example I have a query in a controller:

```
$pg = Page::with('getPanels')->where('slug',$slug)->get();
```

This will return a single result and works fine, so I pass this to a blade template. My complete function is

```
$pg = Page::with('getPanels')->where('slug',$slug)->get();
return view('front.page',['pg' => $pg]);
```

As soon as he template is brought in it will fall over at

```
if (!is_null($pg->headImage))
```

{$img = asset('images/pages')."/".$pg->headImage;}

and I will get

> Property [headImage] does not exist on this collection instance.

If I change the line to

```
if (!is_null($pg[0]['headImage']))
```

it will continue OK. This is of course a pain as I would much rather use $pg->headImage.

Can someone enlighten me please?

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted this and I hope it will help other people.

If I use

```
$pg = Page::with('getPanels')->where('slug',$slug)->first();
```

it will be just one result (naturally) and therefore

```
$pg->headImage
```

will fail as it wants

```
$pg[0]['headImage']
```

but if I change the eloquent instead of get(0 to first() (still just one result)

```
$pg = Page::with('getPanels')->where('slug',$slug)->first();
```

I can use $pg->headImage or what field I want.